# How to run Loki tests in GitHub CI using Chrome.app?

Tags: google-chrome

Loki screenshot tests run successfully locally. All tests work fine on GitHub CI, except for the Loki screenshot tests.

I tried adding the line `npx loki --requireReference --reactUri file:./storybook-static` in the Loki documentation, I have a mistake. The photo of the screen shows what is happening to me.

[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuCQa.png),

[yml script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlVfy.png),

[json loki configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZIvX.png),

[locales good job loki tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUexh.png),

[error on GitHub CI 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fwes.png),

[error on GitHub CI 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EalmU.png)